# Resize uiview's background image depends on text

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create resizable ui view background. It will resize depend on text. I tried following code:

```
let capInsetsIncoming = UIEdgeInsets(top: 17, left: 26.5, bottom: 17.5, right: 21)
self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"profileBioBackground")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(capInsetsIncoming))
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

**This is my background image:**

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `UIImageView` as the background. And also, you have to **split** the original image so that that can be used as *resizable* image.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        contentView.backgroundColor = nil

        let leftBackgroundView = UIImageView()
        let rightBackgroundView = UIImageView()

        let image = UIImage(named: "profileBioBackground")!
        let scale = image.scale
        let size = image.size
        let leftRect = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: size.width / 2 * scale,
            height: size.height * scale
        )
        let rightRect = CGRect(
            x: size.width / 2 * scale,
            y: 0,
            width: size.width / 2 * scale,
            height: size.height * scale
        )

        leftBackgroundView.image = UIImage(
            CGImage: CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, leftRect),
            scale: scale,
            orientation: .Up
        )?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 16))
        rightBackgroundView.image = UIImage(
            CGImage: CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rightRect),
            scale: scale,
            orientation: .Up
        )?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 16, bottom: 4, right: 4))

        leftBackgroundView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        rightBackgroundView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        contentView.insertSubview(leftBackgroundView, atIndex: 0)
        contentView.insertSubview(rightBackgroundView, atIndex: 0)
        let views = ["left": leftBackgroundView, "right": rightBackgroundView]
        contentView.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[left][right(==left)]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
                + NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[left]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
                + NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[right]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        )
    }
}
```

And the Storyboard setup, and the result:

[image: screenshot]